# QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have some problems with Qt. I have a class with a signal who's parameters are strings, and a slot. I'm connecting the signal to the slot in the class constructor. Also, I'm creating a thread in the class constructor. The thread reads data from a server and updates the UI(emits the UpdateMe signal). This is how I connect the signal to the slot:

```
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(UpdateMe(string, string)), this, SLOT(ModifyUI(string, string)));
```

I have a QTreeWidget with some file names. When I rename a file I notify the server and the server notifies the other clients. When I connect a single client there is no problem, but when I connect more than one client a problem appears: when I notify the server from the second client(when I write into the socket) the following error appears:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
```

I tried to register `QVector<int>` with `qRegisterMetaType` but I also have a signal that is emited when I modify an `QTreeWidgetItem` (when I rename the item, for example) and I need to disconnect this signal when I want to change the item's text. If I register `QVector<int>` I can't disconnect this signal and the signal is emitted.

Answer (score 17):

When you register the QVector, does your call look like this?

```
qRegisterMetaType<QVector<int> >("QVector<int>");
```

Once you make this call, you should be able to emit the QVector type over queued connections.

> If I register QVector I can't dissconnect this signal and the signal is emited.

Registering a metatype shouldn't prevent you from disconnecting a signal.  It just allows you to queue types that aren't already registered with the meta system.

Comment: Yes, but I don't emit QVector type. I emit string type. 

        threadData->GetMainUI()->EmitUpdateMe(option, message);

Comment: And that is what I'm doing in the ModifyUI slot:

        QObject::disconnect(this->filesTreeWidget, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)), this, SLOT(OnItemChanged_filesTreeWidget(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
        item->setText(0, QString::fromStdString(newFilename));
        QObject:: connect(this->filesTreeWidget, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)), this, SLOT(OnItemChanged_filesTreeWidget(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: I register QVector<int> like you said but if I register it the dissconect don't work. When I change item's text the itemChanged signal is emited and the OnItemChanged_filesTreeWidget slot is called.

Comment: I couldn't answer to my question because I have less than 10 reputation points. That's why I wrote the code in comments.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what's going on.  If you expand your question with more code, maybe I can help.  It isn't at all clear what's going on.  You should be able to edit your own question, right?

Comment: It's working. The signal was not emited in the thread handler. Thank you for help!

Comment: Where did you expand the code?  The question looks exactly the same as it did when I made the comment.  You have one line of actual code, and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with emitting a signal in a handler thread (none of that was shown in the question).  The lines you added as a comment don't add anything at all on their own.  Basically, the question needs more context.  It seems you've found your problem, so it doesn't matter now.

Comment: So strange...I got this error trying to emit a completely stock `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged`. Wonder why `qRegisterMetaType` wasn't called for `QVector<int>` if Qt (5.15.2) is using that internally?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, errors which look like this seem to be a result of mixing up threads, and specifically with this one, in my (limited) experience, a result of attempting to manipulate GUI elements "held" in the GUI thread using commands run a worker `QThread`.

I say "held" because quite often you get a complaint/error/crash saying something like "QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread." (i.e. the GUI thread).

The solution: from a non-GUI `QThread` ALWAYS communicate with GUI elements using signals and slots.